# How to generate a tuple from a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

```
Dice_1 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]
Dice_2 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]

for a in Dice_1:
    print(a)
for b in Dice_2:
    print(b)
```

What i want is that after one random integer from `Dice_1` and `Dice_2` is generated both form a tuple, then the next pair and so forth, for example `(1,3)` and then `(5,7)`.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip)

```
Dice_1 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]
Dice_2 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]

for a,b in zip(Dice_1,Dice_2):
    print((a,b))
```

Output:

```
(1, 4)
(5, 7)
(7, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) or create tuples to begin with:

```
tups = [(random.randint(1,7), random.randint(1,7)) for _ in range(3)]
```

... btw. those are 7-sided die, quite a rare species.

Another way would be to use the index and value of the first list (via [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)) and index into second list:

```
import random

Dice_1 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]
Dice_2 = [random.randint(1,7) for x in range(3)]

for i,v in enumerate(Dice_1):
    print( (v,Dice_2[i]) )
```

Output:

```
(4, 6)
(6, 7)
(3, 6)
```

Comment: Yes so rare that I didn't realise it was 7-sided.

Comment: @the_R   ;o)  thought so

Answer (score 0):

Easy use zip:

```
for x,y in zip(Dice_1,Dice_2):
  print((x,y))
```

Or to get in a list:

```
[(x,y) for x,y in zip(Dice_1,Dice_2)]
```